# Parse JSON with Vala

Tags: json, glib, vala

I'm trying to parse this JSON document :

```
{
  "registration" : "F-FBZH",
  "model" : "DR400-120"
}
```

This is what I made :

```
public Plane load_airplane (string registration) {
    try {
        string? res = null;
        var file = File.new_for_path (location + registration + ".json");

        if (file.query_exists ()) {
            var dis = new DataInputStream (file.read ());
            string line;

            while ((line = dis.read_line (null)) != null) {
                res += line;
            }

            var parser = new Json.Parser ();
            parser.load_from_data (res);
            var root_object = parser.get_root ().get_object ();

            string data_registration = root_object.get_string_member ("registration");
            string data_model = root_object.get_string_member ("model");

            return new Plane (data_registration, data_model);
        }
    } catch (Error e) {
        stderr.printf ("%s\n", e.message);
    }
    return new Plane.default ();
}
```

It compile without any problem, but when I lunch the program I got these errors:

```
(process:25868): Json-CRITICAL **: json_parser_load_from_data: assertion 'data != NULL' failed

(process:25868): Json-CRITICAL **: json_node_get_object: assertion 'JSON_NODE_IS_VALID (node)' failed

(process:25868): Json-CRITICAL **: json_object_get_string_member: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(process:25868): Json-CRITICAL **: json_object_get_string_member: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

** (process:25868): CRITICAL **: open_plane_plane_construct: assertion 'registration != NULL' failed

** (process:25868): CRITICAL **: open_plane_plane_get_registration: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
(null)
```

Why? Another question, why is it that hard to read a JSON with a middle-level language, Vala? It should be a lot more easier!

Comment: You don't have to use a `DataInputStream`, you can just call `file.load_contents ()`.

Comment: You can also use `Json.from_string ()` if you have a recent `valac` and `json-glib-1.0` packages intalled. It will save you some LOCs as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are initializing your nullable res string as null.

If you then add something to the string it will stay null.

```
string? res = null;
res += "something";
// res will still be null here!
```

You can either initialize it as `""` (empty string and in that case you can just use a non nullable string as well) or you can skip the `DataInputStream` alltogether and use `file.load_contents ()`.

Comment: Or you can use `Json.Parser.load_from_stream()`.

Comment: Thank Jens, you fixed my problem!

Comment: Hey Jens, do you a link/resources to help me understand how to work with JSON in vala? Thanks

Comment: I would start by reading the API docs for json-glib @ valadoc: https://valadoc.org/json-glib-1.0/Json.Parser.html#!

Comment: And of course there is the original C API reference manual: https://developer.gnome.org/json-glib/unstable/